# How to plot fourier-series graph? Was this particular one done correctly? Please see attached image

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq88y.png)

Specifically  b. Did I draw the graph as required? What corrections would you recommend to it?

Comment: No responses yet

Comment: Properly speaking, $f$ is not well-defined for $x >1$. But presumably they want it to be periodic, even if they failed to phrase it correctly. But why did you feel that the parabolic part was only for positive $x$? And what do you know about the behavior of fourier series at jump discontinuities?